# Error with Java ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

I've coding and i can't see the error. It's not an "error" directly, but when i press the color blue, the background won't change color to blue. I've tried to replace this code from the class Meny (ActionListener) to public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e), but it doesn't work.

Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenyTest extends JFrame {
JPanel panel;
JMenuBar menyrad;
JMenu fargmeny, svmeny;
JMenuItem rod, gron, bla, svart, gra, vit;

public MenyTest () {
   panel = new JPanel();
   panel.setBackground(Color.white);
   add(panel);

   menyrad = new JMenuBar();
   fargmeny = new JMenu("Färger");
   svmeny = new JMenu("SvartVitt");
   this.setJMenuBar(menyrad);
   menyrad.add(fargmeny);
   menyrad.add(svmeny);

   rod = new JMenuItem("Röd");
   gron = new JMenuItem("Grön");
   bla = new JMenuItem("Blå");
   svart = new JMenuItem("Svart");
   gra = new JMenuItem("Grå");
   vit = new JMenuItem("Vit");

   fargmeny.add(rod);
   fargmeny.add(gron);
   fargmeny.add(bla);

   svmeny.add(svart);
   svmeny.add(gra);
   svmeny.add(vit);
}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     MenyTest f = new MenyTest();
     f.setSize(500, 500);
     f.setLocation(400, 150);
     f.setTitle("MenyTest");
     f.setDefaultCloseOperation(MenyTest.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     f.setVisible(true);
 }

public class Meny extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   rod.addActionListener(this);
   gron.addActionListener(this);
   bla.addActionListener(this);
   svart.addActionListener(this);
   gra.addActionListener(this);
   vit.addActionListener(this);

   if (e.getSource() == rod) panel.setBackground(Color.red);
   else if (e.getSource() == gron) panel.setBackground(Color.green);
   else if (e.getSource() == bla) panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
   else if (e.getSource() == svart) panel.setBackground(Color.black);
   else if (e.getSource() == gra) panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
   else if (e.getSource() == vit) panel.setBackground(Color.white);  
}
```

Comment: As per your code you are not even able to fire the action event. Is it ok if I use the `MenyTest` as JFrame?

Comment: @utkarsh31 yes it is ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MenyTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JPanel panel;
JMenuBar menyrad;
JMenu fargmeny,svmeny;
JMenuItem rod,gron,bla,svart,gra,vit;

public MenyTest() {
     panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setBackground(Color.white);
       add(panel);

       menyrad = new JMenuBar();
       fargmeny = new JMenu("Färger");
       svmeny = new JMenu("SvartVitt");
       this.setJMenuBar(menyrad);
       menyrad.add(fargmeny);
       menyrad.add(svmeny);

       rod = new JMenuItem("Röd");
       gron = new JMenuItem("Grön");
       bla = new JMenuItem("Blå");
       svart = new JMenuItem("Svart");
       gra = new JMenuItem("Grå");
       vit = new JMenuItem("Vit");

       fargmeny.add(rod);
       fargmeny.add(gron);
       fargmeny.add(bla);

       svmeny.add(svart);
       svmeny.add(gra);
       svmeny.add(vit);
       rod.addActionListener(this);
       gron.addActionListener(this);
       bla.addActionListener(this);
       svart.addActionListener(this);
       gra.addActionListener(this);
       vit.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if (e.getSource() == rod) panel.setBackground(Color.red);
       else if (e.getSource() == gron) panel.setBackground(Color.green);
       else if (e.getSource() == bla) panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
       else if (e.getSource() == svart) panel.setBackground(Color.black);
       else if (e.getSource() == gra) panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
       else if (e.getSource() == vit) panel.setBackground(Color.white);  

}
```

}

```
public class Main  {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        MenyTest f = new MenyTest();
         f.setSize(500, 500);
         f.setLocation(400, 150);
         f.setTitle("MenyTest");
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(new JFrame().EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         f.setVisible(true);
     }


}
```

Comment: I got help from your code, thanks! But i needed to remove the public class Main because i already have 2 classes.

Comment: The better class with main  should be separate, it is convenient